# Looping data and insert into table with Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have 2 tables that are related (**putusan and detail_putusan**).

I made ​​a loop on the controller so that the existing data in the form is taken and then stored into a table detilResult. But I have failed to take all the data. **Only one data**, and **the last** that can be taken and saved to **detail_putusan** table.

How do I retrieve all the data by looping on the controller?

My controller code :

```
public function actionCreate()
{       
    $model = new HasilPutusan;


    if(isset($_POST['HasilPutusan']))
    {
        $HasilPutusan           = new HasilPutusan();
        $DetilSaksi         = new DetilSaksi();
        $HasilPutusan->attributes   = $_POST['HasilPutusan'];

        if($HasilPutusan->save()){         
             foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $key => $count ){
                 $DetilSaksi->id_detil_fk   = $HasilPutusan->id_detil_fk;
                 $DetilSaksi->id_saksi  = $_POST['data_'.$count];
                 $DetilSaksi->save();
             }
             $this->redirect('index');
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

My view :

[image]

My view HTML :

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="rows[]" id="rows_1">
            <select name="data_1" id="data_1" class="small">
                <option value="">- Pilih Data -</option>
                <option value="1">Rian Josh</option>
                <option value="2">Brian Mac</option>
                <option value="3">Widi Astanto</option>
                <option value="4">Edy Gordo</option>
                <option value="5">Jin Kazama</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="rows[]" id="rows_2">
            <select name="data_2" id="data_2" class="small">
                <option value="">- Pilih Data -</option>
                <option value="1">Rian Josh</option>
                <option value="2">Brian Mac</option>
                <option value="3">Widi Astanto</option>
                <option value="4">Edy Gordo</option>
                <option value="5">Jin Kazama</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><a class="remCF" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="3" name="rows[]" id="rows_3">
            <select name="data_3" id="data_3" class="small">
            <option value="">- Pilih Data -</option>
            <option value="1">Rian Josh</option>
            <option value="2">Brian Mac</option>
            <option value="3">Widi Astanto</option>
            <option value="4">Edy Gordo</option>
            <option value="5">Jin Kazama</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><a class="remCF" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift the initialization of DetilSaksi to inside the foreach loop.

```
       if($HasilPutusan->save()){         
             foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $key => $count ){
                 $DetilSaksi         = new DetilSaksi();
                 $DetilSaksi->id_detil_fk   = $HasilPutusan->id_detil_fk;
                 $DetilSaksi->id_saksi  = $_POST['data_'.$count];
                 $DetilSaksi->save();
             }
             $this->redirect('index');
        }
```